# Unity not destroying ontriggerenter2d object with TypeFruit

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am new to Unity and c# and have been learning for a few months now. I have a problem with a project I am working on. In the game, a player runs around picking fruit from trees. I want when the player is colliding an object with the tag "TypeFruit", the fruit is destroyed. The Fruit is not getting picked when the player touches it and I don't know why. Could somebody share there knowledge about this? There are no error messages showing. Thank You.

I have tried this.

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.tag == "TypeFruit")
        {
            Destroy(collision.gameObject);
        }
    }
```

This is the Player script

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class player_movement : MonoBehaviour
{

    int speed=2;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey("w"))
        {
            transform.Translate(0, 0.05f * speed, 0);

        }
        if (Input.GetKey("s"))
        {
            transform.Translate(0, -0.05f * speed, 0);


        }
        if (Input.GetKey("a"))
        {
            transform.Translate(-0.05f * speed, 0, 0);
        }
        if (Input.GetKey("d"))
        {
            transform.Translate(0.05f * speed, 0, 0);
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.tag == "TypeFruit")
        {
            Destroy(collision.gameObject);
        }
    }

}
```

And this is the Fruit script

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Fruit : MonoBehaviour
{
    int Healthiness;



    void Start()
    {




    }

}
```

And this is the treeplacer script. The treeplacer spawns trees randomly across the map. Each tree grows fruit. I want the player to pick the fruit if he touches it. Fruits are tagged with the tag "TypeFruit".

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class TreePlacer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Sprite[] FruitSprites = new Sprite[3];
    public Fruit FruitPrefab;

    public GameObject TreePrefab;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        int TreeCount = Random.Range(8, 16);
        for(int i=1; i<=TreeCount; i++)
        {
          GameObject CurrentTree= Instantiate(TreePrefab, new Vector3(Random.Range(-5, 6), Random.Range(-5, 6), 0), Quaternion.identity);
            CurrentTree.AddComponent(typeof(Tree));
            CurrentTree.GetComponent<Tree>().FruitPrefab = FruitPrefab.gameObject;
            CurrentTree.GetComponent<Tree>().myTreePlacer = this;
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }

    void PlaceTree()
    {

    }

}

public class Tree:MonoBehaviour
{

    public TreePlacer myTreePlacer;
    public GameObject FruitPrefab;
    public int maxNumberOfFruits;
    public int regrowTime;
    public int climbTime;
    int currentNumberOfFruits=0;
    FruitType MyFruitType;




    void Start()
    {

        MyFruitType = (FruitType)Random.Range(0, 3);

        switch (MyFruitType)
        {
            case FruitType.apple:
                maxNumberOfFruits = 5;
                regrowTime = 20;
                climbTime = 5;

                break;

            case FruitType.banana:

                    maxNumberOfFruits = 5;
                        regrowTime = 30;
                    climbTime = 10;
                    break;

            case FruitType.coconut:
                maxNumberOfFruits = 3;
                regrowTime = 60;
                climbTime = 30;
                break;



        }

        StartCoroutine(GrowFruit());




    }

    IEnumerator GrowFruit()
    {

        while (true)
        {

            yield return new WaitForSeconds(regrowTime);

            Fruit CurrentFruit = Instantiate(FruitPrefab, new Vector3(transform.position.x + Random.Range(-0.5f, 0.5f), transform.position.y + Random.Range(-0.5f, 0.5f)), Quaternion.identity).GetComponent<Fruit>();
            CurrentFruit.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = myTreePlacer.FruitSprites[(int)MyFruitType];
            currentNumberOfFruits++;
            yield return new WaitWhile(() => currentNumberOfFruits >= maxNumberOfFruits);
        }
    }



}



enum FruitType
{
    apple, banana, coconut
}
```

No errors at all. Trees spawn perfectly fine. Fruits are also spawning fine but are not getting picked when the player touches it.

Comment: Do you have a Rigidbody2D attached to the fruit? Unfortunatly this is necessary for the onTriggerEnter2D to work.

Comment: I fixed the bug before. Thee was no rigidbody on the fruit. Thanks for mentioning it anyway! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it might be one of these
1. typo in the tag name
2. one of the objects hasn't 2dcollider or rigidbody2d

Comment: I fixed this before. Thank you. The problem was 2. Thanks for helping anyway.